# Ignore xml attributes while converting to JSON node

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-xml

My use case is to parse and convert a piece of input xml into jsonNode, process it and then again convert it into xml for output. I am trying to do it using the jackson library but it wont let me ignore the attributes.

For this example input xml snippet(I'd prefer to ignore the `Qualifier` atttribute):

```
<Roottag xmlns:ns5="http://abc.def.com/foo/bar/default.aspx">
    <ns5:Parent>
        <ns5:Child1 Qualifier="XY">123456</ns5:Child1>
        <ns5:Child2>160</ns5:Child2>
    </ns5:Parent>
</Roottag>
```

The converted Json comes out as :

```
{
    "Parent": {
        "Child1": {
            "Qualifier": "XY",
            "": "123456"
        },
        "Child2": "160",
    }
}
```

On converting this to output xml, it adds an empty tag for the actual value of `Child1`. But the `Qualifier` attribute is of no use to me, and would like to ignore it.

```
<Parent>
   <Child1>
        <Qualifier>XY</Qualifier>
        <>123456</>
    </Child1>
    <Child2>160</Child2>
</Parent>
```

My expected output should look something like this:

```
<Parent>
   <Child1>123456</Child1>
    <Child2>160</Child2>
</Parent>
```

I'm using the following code snippet to convert xml into `JsonNode`:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
Map<String, Object> objMap = xmlMapper.readValue(inputXMLString, Map.class);

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objMap);
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonString);
```

Following code snippet to convert `jsonNode` to output xml:

```
String outputXMLStirng = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
```

Is there a  way jackson library allows you to ignore attributes in xml?

Answer (score 0):

you could recursively search the map and remove desired key

```
public static void recursiveRemoveKey(Map<String, Object> objMap, String key) {
    objMap.remove(key);
    for (Object value : objMap.values()) {
        if (value instanceof Map childMap) {
            recursiveRemoveKey(childMap, key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's doable, but it won't work if there are multiple unknown attributes. It's possible the attribute might not be named `Qualifier` each time. Also, I want to associate the element's value to `Child1` key instead of empty String key.

Comment: you did notice that the solution is a method that accepts arg key to be removed, right?. also, your post with the expected result does not mention this new requirment

Comment: I can see that. What I meant was, the attribute names might differ, other than `Qualifier` which I may not know prior at the time of development. I am looking for a generic way by which ALL the attributes can be ignored. Also, The expected output in my post clearly shows the value `123456` associated to `child1` tag, instead of empty sub tag as depicted in the actual output snippet.

Comment: "I am looking for a generic way by which ALL the attributes can be ignored" yet another new question. you should focus on getting answers one question at a time, and be more precise about the requirements.